# Where is the guy who rewards you for number of Pi'illos rescued in Mario and Luigi: Dream Team?

Tags: mario-luigi-dream-team

At one point, a guy rushed up to me, congratulated me on having rescued several Pi'illos, and told me to come back when I rescued more for more rewards.  I cannot for the life of me remember where he was.

Where do I find that guy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one who rewards you for the number of Pi'illos you've saved is **Eldream**, the purple "old man"-looking Pi'illo. He can be found in the bed of the administrator's residence in **Mushrise Park**, which is where you fought the **Grobot** and also where Brickle is.